# How to write '<' and '>' chars in xsd?

Tags: xml, xsd

```
<xs:element name="BookName" type="xs:string" default="<ABC>"/>
```

For example, I would like set a default value likes above, but it says the '<' and '>' are illegal. How to write '<' and '>' chars in xsd?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

Use entities:

```
<xs:element name="BookName" type="xs:string" default="&lt;ABC&gt;"/>
```

Comment: Actually, I would like to write <![CDATA[tr(<h3>abc</h3><br/>)]]>, how to address this? <xs:element name="BookName" type="xs:string" default="<![CDATA[tr(<h3>abc</h3><br/>)]]>"/>, so that, go to xml, it would be "<![CDATA[tr(<h3>abc</h3><br/>)]]>".

Comment: CDATA sections are not recognized in attribute values; from a language design point of view, they have no utility there, since the parser already knows an attribute value is just a sequence of characters, without any child elements.  So the only way for your desire to be addressed is for you to repress it.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to what Femi said, here's a [reference](http://www.bitjungle.com/isoent/index_files/isoent-ref.pdf) link for future use.

The ISO entity name is referenced with the %xxx; notation, e.g.: &star; yields ☆.  These work in StackExchange posts as well, which is how I displayed the star.

Unfortunately not all of these entities work in XML, but if they don't you can use the &#999; form, where the 999 is the ISO character code for the character you want to display.